# Differntiate between a dropdown list's postback and submit button's postback in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback

I am relatively new to ASP.NET & C#
I am creating a basic form with student name, program dropdown and semester number dropdown. I am using postback to populate semester number dropdown list. I am showing the data i acquired through the form into labels. I am using IsPostBack to populate the labels with data

My problem is that when I change program, it fires the postback to populate semester dropdown and since I am using that event to display data, I cant really select semester number.

How can I differentiate between submit button postback and dropdown postback?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of coding inside the load event handler or using isPostBack. Just use buttons event handler. You can do that by double clicking on button in design view.

However better way of doing this altogether is use .Net Ajax Update Panel with script manager which is very simple to use.

Below is the simple example of using script manger and update panel, you can use it for drop down list so you don't have to postback for that. So postback should be only for button.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
        <p runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDOA" runat="server" Text="Appointment Date :"   Height="21px" 
            Width="136px" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOA" runat="server" CssClass="fieldz" AutoPostBack="true" 
            Visible="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
     </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Instead of textbox in above code you can have dropdown list.

Comment: I thought of using button's onclick event but I thought there could be a better way.
I am just starting so I am not familiar with AJAX extensions but I will keep that in mind. Once I have my current application functional, I will start playing with AJAX

THANKS :)

Comment: Better way is to use onclick event for button but for dropdownlist wrap it up inside the ajax I showed you above this will make web page flicker free.

Comment: UpdatePanels are awesome... until they "randomly stop working in complex use-case scenarios" :( [Don't ask me how I know.]